# Как расположить ползунок на прогресс баре, чтобы указать текущий процент?

Tags: javascript

Помогите сделать прогресс бар - где ползунок указывает текущий процент расположения его по линии 
Например если ползунок по середине - его процент (на нём написать) будет 50%

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Border-radius: <input type="range" id="r1" value="0"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Лень писать заново на нативном, поэтому предложу уже готовый пример с JQuery, что у меня был. Стилизуете сами как Вам захочется. Автор кода -  Andreas Storm. Ссылка на CodePen - https://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/tjowy

```js
(function() {
  $("#range").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      return $(".ui-slider-handle").html(ui.value);
    }
  });

  $(".ui-slider-handle").html("0");

}).call(this);
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#range {
  width: 180px;
  height: 4px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  outline: none;
}
#range .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -17px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #158789;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease;
}
#range .ui-slider-handle:hover,
#range .ui-slider-handle:focus {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#range .ui-slider-range {
  background: #69b6b5;
}
.cntr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="cntr" id="range"></div>
```

Comment: @Arthur, изменилось только одно слово? Просто нужно было `CSS` в кавычки кода поместить?

Comment: Нажмите на `изменён N минут назад`  и увидите внесённые изменения. Были также добавлены пробелы в сниппете.

Comment: @Arthur, замечания учел - благодарю.

Comment: Есть одно НО - процент должен быть на самом ползунку...)

Comment: @v.slobodynuk поправил ответ

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd, по-моему вы взяли это с отсюда — https://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/tjowy =)

Comment: Да, все верно. Это не мой код. И спасибо за ссылку. Щас автора прилеплю

Comment: Спасибо. пока ждал ответа, Сам сделаю, но всё равно Спасибо)))

Comment: @v.slobodynuk не за что, хорошего кода :) Кстати, Вы бы выложили и свою реализацию тоже. Тем кто сюда придет за знаниями, пригодится. Если конечно желаете.

Comment: а как мне сейчас сюда кину свой код ?

Comment: "v.slobodynuk Так тему поправьте и добавьте туда.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getValueInpR = () => {
   let perValue = document.getElementById('percent'),
   printPerValue = document.querySelector('.printPerValue');
   printPerValue.innerText = `${perValue.value}%`;
  }
  percent.addEventListener('input', getValueInpR);
  window.onunload = () => percent.removeEventListener('input', getValueInpR);
```

```css
  #percent {
   outline: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 250px;
   height: 7px;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d0d0d0 70%, #d0d0d0 70%);
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.40), 0 1px 0 rgba(225,255,255,1);
  }
  #percent::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 28px;
   height: 28px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #cf2f5f;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="percent" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" />
 <span class="printPerValue">0%</span>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: как-то так))))))

Comment: забыл кинуть класс чтобы процент не там был ...то есть не в span а в ползунку типа))

Comment: так докиньте.  :)

Comment: То есть все, что Вы изменили с моего первого ответа, это лишь стили тамблера и значение value?